# How to generate capital letter with faker.js

Tags: javascript, faker

I am trying to figureout how to generate uppercase letter with https://github.com/Marak/faker.js but didnt found a solution yet

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a function in faker for that, so just make your own:

```js
const randomCapital = () => String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
console.log(randomCapital());
```

Comment: contribute to faker.js by adding new method for this requirement.